# Is there any security advantage to mounting secrets as a file instead of passing them as environment variables with Docker on Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes

With Docker, there is discussion (consensus?) that passing secrets through runtime environment variables is not a good idea because they remain available as a system variable and because they are exposed with docker inspect.

In kubernetes, there is a system for handling secrets, but then you are left to either pass the secrets as env vars (using envFrom) or mount them as a file accessible in the file system.

Are there any reasons that mounting secrets as a file would be preferred to passing them as env vars?

I got all warm and fuzzy thinking things were so much more secure now that I was handling my secrets with k8s. But then I realized that in the end the 'secrets' are treated just the same as if I had passed them with docker run -e when launching the container myself.

Comment: Remember that anyone who can `docker inspect` a container can also `docker run -v/:/host --rm -it busybox sh` and freely poke around as root on the host filesystem, among other things.  "Visible in `docker inspect`" doesn't sound especially dangerous to me.

Comment: Also remember that, unless you've restricted things with RBAC, it's trivial to `kubectl get secret` and base64 decode the secret values.  On the other hand, IME it's unusual to be able to directly get a shell on a Kubernetes node and poke around: you've mitigated the `docker inspect` issue by restricting who's actually able to run that command.

Comment: Thank you. BMitch's response brought up the real issue with using env vars. Which is that forked processes and other programs also have access to the env vars as well as the fact that many logs and traces may include them as well. So it sounds like docker inspect is not the actual threat to worry about here, since, as you mentioned, you're pretty much screwed if they get docker inspect privileges anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Environment variables aren't treated very securely by the OS or applications. Forking a process shares its full environment with the forked process. Logs and traces often include environment variables. And the environment is visible to the entire application as effectively a global variable.

A file can be read directly into the application and handled by the needed routine and handled as a local variable that is not shared to other methods or forked processes. With swarm mode secrets, these secret files are injected a tmpfs filesystem on the workers that is never written to disk.

Secrets injected as environment variables into the configuration of the container are also visible to anyone that has access to inspect the containers. Quite often those variables are committed into version control, making them even more visible. By separating the secret into a separate object that is flagged for privacy allows you to more easily manage it differently than open configuration like environment variables.

Comment: Most of the arguments listed here against the env apply as well to secret stored as a file.  As soon as an adversary has access to the container, file or env will make no difference. The only valid argument is that env variable can increase the risk to have a disclosure from the logs and traces.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot exactly. My conclusion was that the safest way to ensure a secret is "unusable" even if someone gets access to your container is by making the app inside the container (who needs to consume secrets) to generate a key pair in memory, expose the public key, we use it to encrypt the secrets, store it in the wild (e.g. Vault), pass to container as env or file, then the app can decrypt and use the secret. It doesn't seem scalable, but works for a few very sensitive secrets that even me as the cluster admin don't wanna have access to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , since when you mount the actual value is not visible through docker inspect or other Pod management tools. More over you can enforce file level access at the file system level of the Host for those files.

More suggested reading is here [Kubernets Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Secrets in Kearse used to store sensitive information like passwords, ssl certificates.

You definitely want to mount ssl certs as files in container rather sourcing them from environment variab
les.